# Deploy to AppEngine without changing the GWT files

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have GWT for client side and AppEngine with Java for the server side.
I have noticed that if you GWT compile without changing anything, client side is redeployed with new version (I am guessing timestamp changes somewhere). Is there a way to just deploy the server side .class files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it all gets bundled up in your war directory and deployed as a unit.